# Using COM Callable Wrappers in PLC components

Tags: .net, portability, plc, ccw, iec61131-3

I have a Motorolla based, Programmable Logic Control (PLC) device and I write code in it using IEC-61131 structured programming language. The problem is that I have some complex computation to do, so I am trying to write the code in COM Callable Wrapper. So the question is, Is it possible to access functionality coded in CCW developed on .NET framework to access in Motorola based PLC device??

So in short, also what I mean to ask is that whether this CCW be accessible on a non-.NET Framework devices??

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards
Irfan

Comment: No, that requires PC grade hardware.  You probably ought to start thinking about an OPC server.

Comment: Is the result of the complex calculation mission critical?  In other words, does the calculation give a value which is needed to decide the execution flow of the PLC, in particular for anything which is related to safety (machine or human)?  If the answer is yes then the only real (ie: robust) answer is to grind out the calculation in ST or ladder.  If no, then an OPC client solution (as others have said) is probably what you want.  I use KepWare for some of my systems and it works quite well : http://www.kepware.com/Products/OPC_ClientAce.asp

Comment: yes....its very much related to safety issues. so I think its better to implement things in PLC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You should reimplement your .NET logic in ST (structured text Pascal like IEC-61131 language), or run your .NET logic on PC and then constantly communicate with PLC via some protocol it supports (MODBUS, PROFIBUS...) and write results of your PC based calculations into some PLC tags that will be processed further in PLC.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get an OPC server for your device and then write an OPC client that communicates with the OPC server which implements your logic. That way you can write your program logic in any .NET language (or other language).

You can check with Motorola to see if they have an OPC server for your device.